# Set .Net 4 'useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy' during runtime?

Tags: .net, runtime

Is it possible to set the app.config useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy parameter during runtime (basically before one of the 'affected' assemblies is being loaded?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done via the CLR Hosting APIs.  I [detail the technique here](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/15/setting-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-at-runtime/).

Comment: Reed: just saw that post popping up in my rss reader, too - nice one. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, saved me, thanks.  Needed to set this within an mstest library which could be launched by any number of executables I can neither predict nor configure.