# Running NET 2.0 app in any framework

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I want my NET 2.0 exe to run both in :

- XP with only NET 2.0 installed
- XP with only NET 4.0 installed (or windows 8 that dont have NET 2.0 enabled)

One solution is to create a MyProgram.exe.config file and I write this enties

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
```

It's possible to embbed this entries (or MyProgram.exe.config) in exe? 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

A `.NET .exe` is called an `assembly`.Additionally to the program-data it contains meta-information about your program, so the `CLR` can work with it and so you can perform things like `reflection`.
You can provide information in the assembly, but I'm afraid you can't do what you want so easily. You would need to make your `.exe` check for the installed version of `.NET` and evntually react to it.

Besides, you must not forget, that when creating an assembly you specify the `.NET`-targetframework, i.e. .NET 3.5, .NET 4.0, etc. ... So an assembly for .NET 2.0 will run on .NET 4.0 anyways due to downward-compatibility.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk5f40ct%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for `assemblies` and how they are used and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for the `System.Reflection.Assembly`-class.

Answer (score 0):

The decision which runtime to use is done before your own code loads.  This means that you cannot meaningfully embed the `supportedRuntime` elements in your own code.

However, you usually do not have to.  Supposing you can set *all* your projects, including all third party projects that you will need to reference, to a low enough target framework, they will execute on any higher framework as well.  Preferably on the same one you used at build time.

One of a few potential problems can occur if you are using mixed mode assemblies (C++/CLI).  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750253/set-net-4-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-during-runtime) for a way how to do deal with it without needing the `.exe.config` file, assuming that your executable is not a mixed mode assembly, but some DLLs it uses are.